# How to create a script file from another script file with reference to variables?

Tags: bash-scripting

From inside a bash script, I would like to create a file with a given content.
The content should contain variables expressions "$1", "$2"...

> #!/bin/sh
>   cat < myfile
>   #!/bin/sh
>   command1 $1
>   command2 $2
>   command3 $3
>   EOF

The created file is meant to be used with variables:
./myfile param1 param2 param3

But myfile appears without the variables

```
$ cat myfile
```

> #!/bin/sh
>   command1
>   command2
>   command3

Comment: How are you creating the new script? If you are using `echo` commands, eg `echo 'command1 $1'`, you must stop the expansion of the parameters in the calling script, so you must quote or escape them (as in `echo command1 \$1`), so that the `$` is written literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF > myfile
#!/bin/sh
command1 \$1
command2 \$2
command3 \$3
EOF
```

Two changes were made:

- escape the $ using \
- mark `<<EOF` at the beginning of the section which should be written to myfile (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) for more info)

After running this script, the result of

```
cat myfile
```

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> command1 $1
> command2 $2
> command3 $3
> ```